# rails & jquery, onchange selection auto filling input box

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am working on rails and jquery. I have a selection box called attribute. I wanted to auto fill an input field upon the attribute changes. But if I make an ajax call to a rails function, how does it both redirect back and return the value I want? The code looks like this:

```
function fnGetValue() {
  return $.get(
    "/get_value",
    {attribute: attr}
  );
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#attribute").change(function(event) {
    fnGetValue().done(function(result) {
      $("#value").val(result);
    });
  });
});

def get_value
  ret = get_from_db
  return ret
  #redirect_to :back
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your ruby code.
`return ret` doesn't send the `ret` value back to your browser.

To do so you should use `render`.

```
def get_value
  ret = get_from_db
  render json: {data:ret}
end
```

## UPDATE

Json is the way to share data between Javascript and any other technology.
It can be an array (`[val1, val2]`), or a dictionary (`{key:value, key2:value2}`).
So in your `.done` Javascript method `result` is expected to be either an array or a dictionary.

I believe `get_from_db` return arrays, dictionaries or even string and integer.
So to make sure your Javascript method always get a dictionary we encapsulate it into `{data:ret}`.

Then in your Javascript, doing `result.data` will get you the value you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks Micka. That works for some attributes, but not all. Why?

Comment: it's about 1.30am and I would like to say "Magic!". But I'm going to update my answer to give you some specific examples.